# Keeping captured image as button background even when exitting the application

Tags: android

I have an android application in which I access the camera of the device and capture an image which in turn is automatically set as image button background.
The problem is that whenever I exit the application and open it again, the background of my image button is gone and I have to capture a new one. I need a code for preserving the captured image as image button background.
note: I am not using database, the image is saved in the gallery of the device.

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException{ 
Date now = new Date(); 
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(now); 
String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp +"_"; 
File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); 
File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir); 
mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath(); return image; }

public void newphoto(View v){ 
    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    File photofile = null; 
    try { 
        photofile = createImageFile(); 
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {} 
    if (photofile!=null){ 
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photofile)); 
        startActivityForResult(i,reqCode); 
    }
}

ImageButton myImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.B1);
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath); 
int nh=(int)(myBitmap.getHeight()*(212.0/myBitmap.getWidth())); 
Bitmap s =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 212, nh, true); 
myImage.setImageBitmap(s);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you store a picture, edit your shared preference.

```
prefs.putString("lastTakenPicture", your_path_string);
```

And when your app starts, get that path_string and convert it into `Bitmap` then add it to `ImageButton`

**EDIT:**
A global variable for SharedPreference

```
 private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

And in your `onCreate()` method

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String lastTakenImagePath= sharedPreferences.getString("lastTakenImagePath",null);
if(lastTakenImagePath!=null){
 /*
*Here Convert pathstring to file, file to bitmap 
*and assign bitmap to   imagebutton.
*/
}
```

And after you store a picture in file storage, do this

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
 editor.putInt("lastTakenImagePath", your_image_file_path.toString());
 editor.commit();
```

Comment: May you  provide me with  the complete code with the shared preference?please Praveen

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are saving the pic that you have captured in gallery. The following code will help you retrieve it back.

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
yourImageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: but I want to keep this image as button background even if I exit then come again

Comment: u need to save the filename somewhere like in file or sharedpreference and when the application is started execute the above code